# How do I tweak an image field markup?

Tags: 7, theming, entities, media

I have an image field that is set to link to content. Drupal makes this markup:

```
<a href="/content-page">
  <img src="http://mysite/sites/default/files/image.jpg">
</a>
```

Now I need to tweak the markup and add some styling, for example:

```
<a href="/content-page" style="border-style: none !important;">
  <img src="http://mysite/sites/default/files/image.jpg" style="border: none; outline: none;">
</a>
```

I want to add the inline CSS in this way because the page is for emailing.

What would be the best way to do this? I have tried:

1. Putting the markup into field--myfield.tpl.php and inserting variables, but the `$items` array doesn't give me clean image file or target URLs.
2. Using the [Custom Formatters](http://drupal.org/project/custom_formatters) module, but it gives me AJAX errors for some reason and not sure it would do the job anyway.
3. I could use a preprocess function in template.php, but I am hot sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For link, it's easy to provide in field--myfield.tpl.php:

```
$items[0]['#path']['options']['attributes'] = array('style'=>'border-style: none !important;');
```

But image doesn't have this, so you can miss upper code and rewrite formatter in template.php (add attributes there).

```
/**
 * Returns HTML for an image field formatter.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An associative array containing:
 *   - item: An array of image data.
 *   - image_style: An optional image style.
 *   - path: An array containing the link 'path' and link 'options'.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function YOURTHEMENAME_image_formatter($variables) {
  $item = $variables['item'];
  $image = array(
    'path' => $item['uri'],
    'alt' => $item['alt'],
  );
  // Do not output an empty 'title' attribute.
  if (drupal_strlen($item['title']) > 0) {
    $image['title'] = $item['title'];
  }

  if ($variables['image_style']) {
    $image['style_name'] = $variables['image_style'];
    $output = theme('image_style', $image); // Here you should add attribute, check that it's your field.
  }
  else {
    $output = theme('image', $image);
  }

  if (!empty($variables['path']['path'])) {
    $path = $variables['path']['path'];
    $options = $variables['path']['options'];
    // When displaying an image inside a link, the html option must be TRUE.
    $options['html'] = TRUE;
    $output = l($output, $path, $options);  // Here you should add attribute, check that it's your field. Or just take upper code.
  }

  return $output;
}
```